# Run WebSocket Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I got my new Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and decided to run a WebSocket server on it. I have never used Node.js or Socket.io before, so I used these tutorials both made from the same person:

Installing Node.js on a Raspberry Pi - http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/raspberry-pi-installing-nodejs/

Using WebSockets on a Raspberry Pi - http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/raspberry-pi-getting-interactive-with-your-server-using-websockets/

After successfully installing Node.js using the first tutorial, I went on to the second tutorial and was able to set up a server with an HTML page. When I tried to start up the WebSocket server, I got the following error in terminal: `Cannot find module 'engine.io'`. I tried uninstalling and re-installing socket.io, I also tried re-installing my OS and trying again. Nothing happened.

Am I doing something wrong or is this tutorial from 2014 just out of date? If it is, how would I go about starting up my WebSocket server?

Comment: Did you just missed `npm install engine.io --save`?

Comment: do I have to individually do that for every module? It said nothing about doing that in the tutorial.

Comment: No, engine.io [is a dependency of socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/1.4.5/package.json#L24), so it should be automatically installed under socket.io when you install it.

Comment: ...that said, did `npm install socket.io` actually work or was there an error message?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet. I wiped my SD card before I decided I should just ask a question

Comment: Also, that first tutorial has you using a very old version of node.  We're on 4.3 (LTS) / 5.7 (stable) now.

Comment: I tried to install a newer version, but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: [Building instructions on the wiki.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-linux)  Basically  `git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git`, `cd node`, `git checkout v5.7.0`, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it working